Why doesn't Ubuntu 24.04 recognize jack headset as audio input?
I recently encountered a problem on my Ubuntu 24.04 where a jack headset that I connect via AUX is not recognized as audio input. I don't know whether it worked before at some point or not.
In Pulse Audio Volume Control,  when selecting "Show All Input Devices", I see my laptop's microphone in "built-in audio analog stereo". When plugged in, my headset is detected as plugged in in the category "monitor of built-in audio analog stereo". However, I cannot select it in the category "built-in audio analog stereo" (input) and therefore cannot use it as audio input. The headset is nonetheless detected as "built-in audio analog stereo" output device.
I tested multiple jack headsets all of which have a built in microphone and none of them could be detected as input
Some tests:
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

# headset unplugged
$ for C in /proc/asound/card[0-9]*/codec*; do echo $C; cat $C; done > /tmp/a.log
# headset plugged
$ for C in /proc/asound/card[0-9]*/codec*; do echo $C; cat $C; done > /tmp/b.log
$ diff /tmp/{a,b}.log
26c26
<   Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
---
>   Amp-Out vals:  [0x57 0x57]
39c39
<   Amp-Out vals:  [0x27 0x27]
---
>   Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
136c136
<   Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
---
>   Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
262c262
<   Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
---
>   Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]


$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep -i jack
  Pin Default 0x0421101f: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI

Can somebody help interpret these results?

"jack headphone that I connect via AUX is not recognized as audio input." Do you mean a headset, which has a microphone as well as earphone, and is an input/output device, or headphone, i.e., earphone only, which is exclusively an output device? Make/model of the device, and/or pic might help. Otherwise, we're just tilting at windmills.

@DrMoishePippik headset
